# Spock error: cannot find shared instance field

Tags: grails, groovy, spock, geb

I just cloned the example project [geb-grails-example](https://github.com/geb/geb-example-grails) and facing an error related to Spock.

When running the grails (2.0.3) command `test-app`, I get the following error:

```
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/geb-example-grails
| Server stopped
| Tests PASSED - view reports in target\test-reports
| Error Error running script test-app --stacktrace: cannot find shared instance field (NOTE:         Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.spockframework.util.InternalSpockError: cannot find shared instance field
at org.spockframework.runtime.SpecInfoBuilder.getSharedInstanceField(SpecInfoBuilder.java:119)
at org.spockframework.runtime.SpecInfoBuilder.buildSharedInstanceField(SpecInfoBuilder.java:107)
at org.spockframework.runtime.SpecInfoBuilder.doBuild(SpecInfoBuilder.java:58)
at org.spockframework.runtime.SpecInfoBuilder.build(SpecInfoBuilder.java:42)
at org.spockframework.runtime.Sputnik.getSpec(Sputnik.java:78)
at org.spockframework.runtime.Sputnik.runExtensionsIfNecessary(Sputnik.java:86)
at org.spockframework.runtime.Sputnik.getDescription(Sputnik.java:55)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.describeChild(Suite.java:123)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.describeChild(Suite.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.getDescription(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:156)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:117)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
at grails.plugin.spock.test.GrailsSpecTestType.doRun(GrailsSpecTestType.groovy:73)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure4.doCall(_GrailsTest_groovy:290)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure4.call(_GrailsTest_groovy)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsTest_groovy:248)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure1_closure21.doCall(_GrailsTest_groovy:195)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsTest_groovy:184)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
at TestApp$_run_closure1.doCall(TestApp.groovy:82)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
| Error Error running script test-app --stacktrace: cannot find shared instance field
```

Any help or pointer would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks in advance

Notes:

I am using

Geb version is 0.7 and Spock version is 0.6

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Problem-in-testing-my-controller-in-spock-td4495752.html)

Comment: Yes, I wrote my test based on what I read from this thread. Thanks for checking though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recloned the repo on my new system and all the tests passed. I don't know the cause for the previous error. Closing the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same problem (using Geb 0.7.0, Spock 0.6, Grails 2.0.3 & Groovy 1.8.6). One workaround i've found is to change the spec to extend from GebSpec instead of GebReportingSpec. Tests pass following this change - but I don't know what the longer term effects of this are (I'm pretty new to this stack).

Answer (score 1):

Try running the test using the -noreloading flag:

> grails -noreloading test-app

Answer (score 0):

```
grails clean
grails compile
grails package
```

cleared this up for me